# Cannot install gcc-4.8 because of unmet dependencies

Tags: installation, 13.10, ppa, dependencies, gcc

I was trying to upgrade **gcc-4.8.1** to **gcc-4.8.2** using **Synaptic** from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test). The installation executed with no problem, but suddenly I had **no gcc-4.8 at all**. I was using gcc-4.7 and gcc-4.8 together, but only 4.7 is left for some reason. Then I tried to reinstall gcc-4.8 using `apt-get install` but I got **unmet dependencies errors**. I tried to solve this problem using [the answers to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies), but to no avail.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

results in:

```
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.8 : Depends: binutils (>= 2.23.90.20131017) but
2.23.52.20130913-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here are the outputs of:

```
martin@martin-Studio-1537:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-proposed main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu saucy main
```

and

```
martin@martin-Studio-1537:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
# deb http://download.mendeley.com/apt/ stable main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/p12/qtcreator/ubuntu saucy main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/p12/qtcreator/ubuntu saucy main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/p12/qtcreator/ubuntu saucy main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/p12/qtcreator/ubuntu saucy main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu saucy main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu saucy main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu saucy main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu saucy main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu saucy main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu saucy main
```

I tried to repeat the suggestions in the answers after **disabling all PPAs** and then again with the gcc-4.8.2 PPA **enabled** and I still cannot install gcc-4.8.2.

What did I do wrong and how can I fix my system?

**EDIT:**

I tried

```
martin@martin-Studio-1537:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for martin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but the result is the same.

I tried everything in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/64420) with the exception of purging or removing PPAs.

**EDIT2:**

I followed instructions from [searchforgold6789's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/424880/64420) and it did work! I successfully installed gcc-4.8.1. But when I added the PPA again and tried to upgrade, I got the following output:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  cpp-4.8 g++-4.8 gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base libasan0 libatomic1 libgcc-4.8-dev
  libgcc1 libgcc1-dbg libgfortran3 libgomp1 libitm1 libquadmath0
  libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++6 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libcloog-isl4 libisl10
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
```

**EDIT3:**

When I do a `apt-get dist-upgrade` it suggests that g++-4.8 gcc-4.8 should be **removed**. Why is this so? Should I proceed? I think this was the reason I got into this trouble in the first place.

```
martin@martin-Studio-1537:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  g++-4.8 gcc-4.8
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cpp-4.8 gcc-4.8-base libasan0 libatomic1 libgcc-4.8-dev libgcc1 libgcc1-dbg
  libgfortran3 libgomp1 libitm1 libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++6
  libstdc++6-4.8-dbg
14 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 32.4 MB disk space will be freed.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you should clean up the old ppa...

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge 
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

Then, go into Software Sources and make sure you have the **universe** and **multiverse** repositories enabled. Do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you should be able to install `gcc-4.8`:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

After that, I would be highly surprised if you could not add the PPA and try again with GCC 4.8.2, successfully.

Comment: Thank you! It worked to an extent. However I still cannot upgrade to 4.8.2. Please, could you look at my EDIT2?

Comment: You should just tap Enter when you see that message.

Comment: @searchforgold6789 but the problem is that the packages that I am trying to install are "held back". How can I make them un-(held back)? Or is this a topic for a different question?

Comment: You should use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: @searchforgold6789 I did so, but it suggests that gcc 4.8 and g++ 4.8 be removed (see Edit3). Is this OK? Can I install them after?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
apt-get install -f

apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question to add the output of these commands.